# Pop-up overlay (modal) in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overlay

I am using AngularJS to build my photography website.

I I want to create a overlay dialog whenever users clicks on the image.

inside ng-view:

```
<div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="item in SouthKorea">  
     <a href=""> <img ng-click="openOverlay($event)"  ng-src="{{item}}" >  </a>
</div>
```

Inside index.html, where different ng-views are loaded into.

```
<div id="overlay">  </div>
```

Inside controller, I have this function

```
$scope.openOverlay = function (e,elem, $scope) {
            var image = angular.element(e.target);
            var overlay = angular.element('#overlay');
            overlay.append(image)
        }
```

My problem is that the image is removed when it's clicked, and I can't figure out how to change display style of overlay element (div#overlay) which is inside index.html.

Answer (score 0):

UI Bootstrap, from the AngularUI team, includes a Modal directive. It also has a good number of other handy modules.